# octave, matlab, plotting in two different plots

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

the question is how to plot two different plots simultaneously in matlab or octave.
I have loop, during execution in that loop there are data which should be plotted in two different plots.  After execution of the loop I want to save these plots to disc.
How implement plotting in two different plots simultaneously?
As I understand, I should create somehow two different handles, then plot using these handles and finally save these plots using handles.
Any ideas how to do it?
UPDATE:
one more question: how to plot into the handler without showing of plot itself. I have lots of iterations in the loop, so it is annoying to close all windows with plots, when I just need them saved into files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expanded a bit on @Pursuit's answer and added a more explicit loop where the data is created and plotted iterativly. Note that you could use figure() to create a new figure handle regardless of what you currently have active:

```
%Create figures, and set hold
f1 = figure(); hold on
f2 = figure(); hold on

%Variables for arbitrary loop
done = 0;
counter = 0;
n = 100;
while not(done)
    %Activate figure 1 and plot
    %figure(f1); %Comment in to switch between windows for each update
    set(0,'CurrentFigure',f1) %Comment out if above line is used instead
    plot(counter,rand,'r.')

    %Activate figure 2
    figure(f2);
    plot(counter+10,rand*10,'ro');

    counter = counter + 1;
    if counter >= n
        done = 1;
    end
end 

%Save figures
saveas(f1, 'figure_1.tiff','tiff'); 
saveas(f2, 'figure_2.tiff','tiff');
```

Comment: Replacing "figure(f1);" in loop with: "set(0,'CurrentFigure',f1)" should avoid the windows popping up over each other all the time.

Comment: or you could "set(f1,'Visible','off'); set(f2,'Visible','off')" and in case then turn them "on" when the job is done

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fig1 = 1937612;  %Random numbers unlikely to conflict with other figures already present
fig2 = 1073131;

for ix = 1:n
    figure(fig1);
    %Plot stuff here
    saveas(fig1, ['figure_1_' num2str(ix) '.tiff'],'tiff');  %Note incrementing filenames

    figure(fig2)
    %Plot stuff here
    saveas(fig2, ['figure_2_' num2str(ix) '.tiff'],'tiff');  %Note incrementing filenames
end
```